# Individually select page experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-settings, chart-web-part, sitepages, new-experience

Is there a way to select the page experience per page, and not 'all or none'?

I currently have 6 pages I would like set to 'new experience', whilst the remaining 50+ pages remain in classic.

The reason I need these 6 pages in new experience, is that I would like them to contain a graph, and I understand the only way to achieve this is to have them set to 'new experience', for the chart webpart to be available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no such feature available at page scope to render a modern page back to classic experience. The modern page experience is based out on the new site pages content type.

You could create these 6 pages using modern UI UX of Site Page content type and the rest 50 pages you could use other content type (wiki page for example).